# DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION - how to identify the issue

Tags: windows-10, dpc

My laptop keeps crashing after playing the new COD: Warzone and it keeps reporting the DPC Watchdog Violation error. I'm using Windows 10 and I've never experienced this issue before. I'm not quite sure how to diagnose this problem. I have located the minidump file and analyzed it with Windbg but I'm not quite sure where to look for the problem. Would appreciate some help and guidance.

**Minidump:**

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25200.1003 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\112222-36437-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is:
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff805`42000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff805`42c2a2b0
Debug session time: Tue Nov 22 10:28:16.830 2022 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 12:36:12.515
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
........................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
................................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff805`423f92d0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffffb080`70f71e20=0000000000000133
2: kd> !analyze -v

---

- ```
                                                                          *
  ```
- ```
                     Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
  ```
- ```
                                                                          *
  ```

---

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
DISPATCH_LEVEL or above.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period (in ticks).
Arg3: fffff80542cfb320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000

### Debugging Details:

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys

---

---

---

***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***

---

***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***

---

***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***

---

***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***

---

---

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

```
Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
Value: 5655

Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
Value: Create

Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 68874

Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
Value: 389

Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 9816

Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
Value: 83

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.DumpHeader
Value: 0x133

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.Register
Value: 0x133

Key  : WER.OS.Branch
Value: vb_release

Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

Key  : WER.OS.Version
Value: 10.0.19041.1
```

FILE_IN_CAB:  112222-36437-01.dmp

BUGCHECK_CODE:  133

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 1e00

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80542cfb320

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffa9857dc3e210 -- (.trap 0xffffa9857dc3e210)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000050a47
rdx=000000000014291c rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8055f6dab6c rsp=ffffa9857dc3e3a0 rbp=ffffdb0f38fe7ba8
r8=ffffa9857dc3e3e8  r9=000000000014291c r10=0000000000000000
r11=000000000000000c r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
nvlddmkm+0x9ab6c:
fffff805`5f6dab6c 488b5c2430      mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h] ss:ffffa985`7dc3e3d0=ffffdb0f38fe7000
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)

BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)

BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)

BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  cod.exe

STACK_TEXT:
ffffb080`70f71e18 fffff805`4245bf02     : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00001e00 fffff805`42cfb320 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb080`70f71e20 fffff805`422d2973     : 00003e70`148448d9 ffffb080`70f58180 00000000`00000000 ffffb080`70f58180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x186d32
ffffb080`70f71e80 fffff805`422d245a     : ffffdb0f`318c30e0 ffffa985`7dc3e290 fffff805`533ad800 00000000`00008201 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453
ffffb080`70f71f30 fffff805`42208a45     : ffffdb0f`318c30e0 ffffb080`70f71f40 00000000`00000010 ffff6b92`0cee485c : nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1a
ffffb080`70f71f60 fffff805`423fb26a     : ffffa985`7dc3e290 ffffdb0f`318c30e0 ffffdb0f`38feab48 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
ffffb080`70f71fb0 fffff805`423fba37     : 00000000`0014280c fffff805`5f6eb15a ffffdb0f`38fe7000 fffff805`423fba44 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
ffffa985`7dc3e210 fffff805`5f6dab6c     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014291c 00000000`00000003 ffffdb0f`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
ffffa985`7dc3e3a0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`0014291c 00000000`00000003 ffffdb0f`00000000 00000000`00000020 : nvlddmkm+0x9ab6c

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+9ab6c

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  9ab6c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {f97493a5-ea2b-23ca-a808-8602773c2a86}

---

**Memory.dmp:**

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25200.1003 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is:
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff805`42000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff805`42c2a2b0
Debug session time: Tue Nov 22 10:28:16.830 2022 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 12:36:12.515
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
........................
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 00000050`b5946018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details Loading unloaded module list ................................ For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v nt!KeBugCheckEx: fffff805`423f92d0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffffb080`70f71e20=0000000000000133
2: kd> !analyze -v

---

- ```
                                                                          *
  ```
- ```
                     Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
  ```
- ```
                                                                          *
  ```

---

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
DISPATCH_LEVEL or above.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period (in ticks).
Arg3: fffff80542cfb320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000

### Debugging Details:

Unable to load image \SystemRoot\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvami.inf_amd64_a5ef29d5e04efca5\nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2

---

---

---

***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***

---

***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***

---

***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***

---

***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***

---

---

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

```
Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
Value: 5374

Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
Value: Create

Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 11423

Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
Value: 0

Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
Value: 405

Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 24406

Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
Value: 86

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.DumpHeader
Value: 0x133

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.KiBugCheckData
Value: 0x133

Key  : Bugcheck.Code.Register
Value: 0x133

Key  : WER.OS.Branch
Value: vb_release

Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

Key  : WER.OS.Version
Value: 10.0.19041.1
```

FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

BUGCHECK_CODE:  133

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 1e00

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80542cfb320

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffa9857dc3e210 -- (.trap 0xffffa9857dc3e210)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000050a47
rdx=000000000014291c rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8055f6dab6c rsp=ffffa9857dc3e3a0 rbp=ffffdb0f38fe7ba8
r8=ffffa9857dc3e3e8  r9=000000000014291c r10=0000000000000000
r11=000000000000000c r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
nvlddmkm+0x9ab6c:
fffff805`5f6dab6c 488b5c2430      mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h] ss:ffffa985`7dc3e3d0=ffffdb0f38fe7000
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)

BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)

BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)

BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  cod.exe

STACK_TEXT:
ffffb080`70f71e18 fffff805`4245bf02     : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00001e00 fffff805`42cfb320 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb080`70f71e20 fffff805`422d2973     : 00003e70`148448d9 ffffb080`70f58180 00000000`00000000 ffffb080`70f58180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x186d32
ffffb080`70f71e80 fffff805`422d245a     : ffffdb0f`318c30e0 ffffa985`7dc3e290 fffff805`533ad800 00000000`00008201 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453
ffffb080`70f71f30 fffff805`42208a45     : ffffdb0f`318c30e0 ffffb080`70f71f40 00000000`00000010 ffff6b92`0cee485c : nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1a
ffffb080`70f71f60 fffff805`423fb26a     : ffffa985`7dc3e290 ffffdb0f`318c30e0 ffffdb0f`38feab48 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
ffffb080`70f71fb0 fffff805`423fba37     : 00000000`0014280c fffff805`5f6eb15a ffffdb0f`38fe7000 fffff805`423fba44 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
ffffa985`7dc3e210 fffff805`5f6dab6c     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014291c 00000000`00000003 ffffdb0f`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
ffffa985`7dc3e3a0 fffff805`5f71b855     : ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffdb0f`38fe7ba8 00000000`0014291c ffffdb0f`38fe7b00 : nvlddmkm+0x9ab6c
ffffa985`7dc3e3d0 fffff805`5fb8e5f0     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff805`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0xdb855
ffffa985`7dc3e450 fffff805`5fb898ca     : 00000000`00000002 ffffdb0f`38c72260 ffffdb0f`39614000 00000000`00000001 : nvlddmkm+0x54e5f0
ffffa985`7dc3e490 fffff805`5fb88bfc     : ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffa985`236f0030 ffffa985`7dc3e5a9 00000000`00000001 : nvlddmkm+0x5498ca
ffffa985`7dc3e4f0 fffff805`5fb94c95     : 00000000`00000001 ffffdb0f`38c72260 00000000`00000002 ffffdb0f`39614000 : nvlddmkm+0x548bfc
ffffa985`7dc3e610 fffff805`5fb94da4     : 00000000`236f2000 ffffdb0f`236f0020 ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffdb0f`39614000 : nvlddmkm+0x554c95
ffffa985`7dc3e680 fffff805`5fab4af8     : ffffa985`236f0030 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000004 ffffa985`7dc3e700 : nvlddmkm+0x554da4
ffffa985`7dc3e6d0 fffff805`5f7d3308     : ffffdb0f`39614000 ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffa985`7dc3e820 ffffa985`7dc3e840 : nvlddmkm+0x474af8
ffffa985`7dc3e730 fffff805`5f72eebb     : 00000000`00000000 fffff805`5ff5f408 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000002a : nvlddmkm+0x193308
ffffa985`7dc3e760 fffff805`5f72e390     : ffffdb0f`38fe7000 fffff805`5f6d002a ffffdb0f`6a0e002a fffff805`5fae1324 : nvlddmkm+0xeeebb
ffffa985`7dc3e7a0 fffff805`5f72ec45     : ffffdb0f`6a0e6810 ffffdb0f`396cc000 ffffdb0f`396cc001 ffffdb0f`396cd700 : nvlddmkm+0xee390
ffffa985`7dc3e810 fffff805`5f72f71a     : ffffdb0f`38fe7000 00000000`00000000 ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffa985`7dc3e9e0 : nvlddmkm+0xeec45
ffffa985`7dc3e880 fffff805`5f6dad57     : ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffdb0f`396cc000 ffffdb0f`38fe7000 ffffdb0f`396cc000 : nvlddmkm+0xef71a
ffffa985`7dc3e8e0 fffff805`4223489e     : ffffb080`70f5b240 ffffdb0f`31ae6000 ffffa985`7dc3ee80 ffffb080`70f58180 : nvlddmkm+0x9ad57
ffffa985`7dc3ebb0 fffff805`42233b84     : ffffb080`70f58180 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000004 : nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0x30e
ffffa985`7dc3ed20 fffff805`424017c5     : 00000000`00000000 ffffb080`70f58180 ffffb080`758f4640 00000000`00000001 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x1f4
ffffa985`7dc3efb0 fffff805`424015b0     : fffff805`423f53e0 fffff805`4232300a 00000050`b87e8f18 00007ff7`77b60768 : nt!KxRetireDpcList+0x5
ffffa985`8260dac0 fffff805`42400d35     : 00000000`00000001 fffff805`423fb331 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000048 : nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue
ffffa985`8260daf0 fffff805`423fb331     : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000048 00000000`00000000 ffffdb0f`00000000 : nt!KiDpcInterruptBypass+0x25
ffffa985`8260db00 00007ffc`588f7a59     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0xb1
00000050`b87e2ec0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`588f7a59

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+9ab6c

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  9ab6c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {f97493a5-ea2b-23ca-a808-8602773c2a86}

---

Thank you!

Comment: It's easier if you provide the analysis dump from WinDBG yourself

Comment: @Ramhound I've added the 2 most recent files (Minidump and memory.dmp) analyzed with Windbg.

Comment: WinDBG calling out `nvlddmkm.sys` is an Nvidia driver (or hardware) problem.

Comment: My suggestion is if the system is stable enough to upgrade to 21H2 or 22H2 since 19041 is actually not currently supported.